# Output the corresponding value as well for the other chosen value (DO Loops)

Tags: if-statement, fortran, do-loops

```
PROGRAM ONE

REAL:: num1 = 200,num2 = 16,num3 = 10,num4
REAL:: counter,smallest

WRITE(*,*) "    Counter", "     num4"
WRITE(*,*) "    --------------------"
DO counter = 0.1,8,0.1
  num4 = (num1 * num2 * num3)/(counter * sqrt(num3**2 - counter**2))
  WRITE(*,*) counter,num4

  IF (counter == 0.1) THEN
     smallest = num4
  END IF

  IF (num4 < smallest) THEN
     smallest = num4
  END IF  

END DO
WRITE(*,*) "The smallest num4 is:", smallest

STOP
END PROGRAM ONE
```

The program needs to be ran to understand what I am trying to say.

This finds and displays the lowest `num4` value. What I also do want it to display is the corresponding `counter` value to the `num4` value. That `counter` value will go along with the last `WRITE` statement. It should say:

```
WRITE(*,*) "The smallest num4 is:", smallest, "for", counter
```

The output should be:

```
The smallest num4 is 640.021 for 7.10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new variable to save off the counter value that corresponds to the smallest value of `num4`.

So near the top of your program have:

```
REAL:: counter,smallest,smallCtr
```

and then set that in the `IF` blocks when you assign to `smallest`:

```
IF (counter == 0.1) THEN
  smallest = num4
  smallCtr = counter
END IF

IF (num4 < smallest) THEN
  smallest = num4
  smallCtr = counter
END IF
```

and then you can write it out along with `smallest`:

```
WRITE(*,*) "The smallest num4 is:", smallest, "for", smallCtr
```